# Fast way to check if a javascript array is binary (contains only 0 and 1)

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary, boolean

What is a quick way to determine if an array is only composed of 0's and 1's?

I'm vaguely familiar with a boolean solution but am not away how to implement it. In order to implement is you would have to assign values to the boolean

```
true = 0
```

and

```
false = 1
```

But how would you implement this if you are given an array such that

```
array = [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]

isArrayBool (){ 

}
```

Comment: `array.every(v => v === 0 || v === 1)`

Comment: note ... `true=1` and `false=0` is more logical ... especially since `+true` === `1` and `+false` ===  `0`

Comment: Faster way would be to use a `for` loop.

Comment: yes, because using .every on an 8 length array is so much slower than a for loop ... nanoseconds are precious ... `array.some(v => v !== 0 && v !== 1);` better?

Comment: @JaromandaX Curious why you deleted the `Set` comment. Is there a problem with that solution?

Comment: No, just think it's probably overkill

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - I see why you say a for loop is faster - because Chrome native array methods (some, every, etc) are pitifully slow

Answer (score 3):

Very very naive solution:

```js
function isArrayBool(array) {
    for (var i of array) {
         if (i !== 0 && i !== 1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(isArrayBool([1,0,0,0,1]));   // true
console.log(isArrayBool([1]));           // true
console.log(isArrayBool([2,3,0]));       // false
```

Comment: It is "in" not "of"

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir my code works smoothly, I think the choice of ```i``` as an object and not as an index confused you.

Comment: so, why does `isArrayBool([0,1,1,1,1])` produce **false** - I think your lack of knowledge between of and in has confused you @DanieleCappuccio

Comment: @DanieleCappuccio put a `console.log(i)` under your `for` and see what it says.

Comment: Guys you are right, I was pretty sure about this. Editing my answer :)

Comment: @Nerdi.org What is `is_bool`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot we made that one custom for our company projects. My answer below has the replacement for that.

Comment: https://jsperf.com/bool-array-test-2/1 This speedtest shows a simple for loop is a lot faster

Answer (score 2):

So I threw a few functions together in jsperf to test. The fastest one I found so far is the one below (which is much faster than the `for of` version):

```
function isBoolFor(arr) {
  for(var i=arr.length-1; i>=0; --i){
    if(arr[i] !== 0 && arr[i] !== 1) return false
  }
  return true
}
```

Comparison is [here](https://jsperf.com/binary-array-check)

---

EDIT: I played around with another version that turned out to be quicker:

```
function isBoolFor(arr) {
  for(var i=0; arr[i] === 0 || arr[i] === 1; i++){}
  return i === arr.length
}
```

The key here is that because most of the array you are checking will consist of zeros and ones, you can avoid doing two boolean checks every iteration by using the `||` instead of the `&&` negative check. It is only a subtle improvement, and could be argued to be no better than the one above in practicality.

---

UPDATE: So the difference between all the for and while variants is too subtle to declare an overall winner. So in that case I would go for readability. If you want binary use typed arrays!

---

FINAL UPDATE:

I was curious and wanted to find an even faster version, and it can be done if the array is known to be only numbers. If the array contains only numbers, then you can use a bitwise operator check for either of the values in question.  For example:

```
function isBoolFor(arr) {
  const test = ~0x01
  for(var i=arr.length-1; i>=0; --i){
    if(test & arr[i]){ return false }
  }
  return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsperf.com/bool-array-test-2/1

As we can see here, the fastest way to do this can be seen here... With a simple for loop, as suggested by user Jaromanda in a comment. This for loop blows other solutions out of the water in terms of speed.

```
 var someArray = [1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0]; 

 function simpleForLoop(array){
   var numArgs = someArray.length;
   for(var loop = 0; loop < numArgs; loop++){
    var arg = someArray[loop];
    if(arg  !== 0 && arg !== 1){ return false; }
   }
   return true;
  }

  var isbool = simpleForLoop(someArray);
```

Comment: Yeah, embarrassingly so. I deleted my other answer because although it is better than the other answers, it's so far behind a simple for loop. I use them all the time in PHP and JS, but to be honest I thought the .every() function would beat out the for (because it stops when my function returns it's first false, so it doesn't hit every array val - for does too, but figured every() would beat it. Nope!)... but I was wrong. for loops win again!

Comment: Yeah, it forgivable to think a javascript built-in would perform close to c -speed. But please check, the `&&` I think you want `||`

Comment: Well, we are saying if the array value is not 0 AND it's not 1, then it's not boolean and return false. otherwise, return true. If we use || then it's saying if it's 0 OR it's not 1, return false... meaning that if it's 1, it will return false because it says to return if it's not 1 OR 0, and it's not 0... So we use && for "AND".

Comment: I'm sorry, it's late that's not the problem… it's that you are returning after the test in both cases. Which means you never test more than the first value. Try running it with: `var someArray = [1,2,2];` You need to put the final `return` outside the `for` loop. p.s. this has am effect on the speed tests, obviously.

Comment: Yeah, that shouldn't be insde the for()

Comment: With all the adjustments throughout this question... My first answer finally fell behind the isArrayBool() function. For loop still ahead, but the isArrayBool() ends up at only 49% slower than the simple for(), as opposed to the 99% before. Good adjustments...hopefully someone finds this all useful lmao

Comment: Thanks for sticking with it. I think it was worthwhile.

Comment: LOL @Nerdi.org You realise that your *fast* function in the perf test has an error that means it doesn't even run a single iteration. I have cleaned your version up and added it to the perf test in my earlier and correct answer...it is equally as fast as the other for variants I posted (but far from embarrassingly as you state). I also want to point out that your perf test is flawed anyway, because you only test the positive case.

Comment: Matt, I am not sure where you are looking, but all issues with the perf test were fixed yesterday & all are running correct iterations. You may be looking at an old version or something

Comment: You are right. The first two lines of your function confused me: `function nerdiForLoop(array){  var numArgs = someArray.length;` Notice how your function uses someArray, but expects an array to be passed as a param.

Comment: Function params don't have to match up with actual variable or array names. It's a reference to anything the dev passes through that function. Honestly, stop trying to nitpick and go learn JS. There's literally nothing wrong with my answer mate.